# How to call Windows Azure Storage RestFul Service without SDK?

Tags: rest, api, azure, sdk, storage

I try to use Windows Azure like a Storage fom Salesforce.com.

I cheked the documentation and I only can see call the calls to azure rest api from SDK (Java, .Net, JS, etc) examples.

I need integrate Salesforce with Windows Azure Storage but, Azure don't have a SDK for Salesforce.com

From Salesforce.com is allow the calls to rest services but the process to call Azure Rest Services require one o more librarys.

Exameple:

Authentication for the Azure Storage Services require of:

- Headers: Date Header and Authorization Header

The Authorization Header require two elments

- SharedKey
- Account Name
- Authorization="[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] :"

SharedKey and Account Name give a conversion:

- HMAC-SHA256 conversion
- over UTF-8 encoded

For this convertion the documentation referes to SDK Librarys in others words Java Class or .Net Class type helper that in Salesforce.com not exist.

Please, I need a example to call the authentification service without sdk

Sorry for my bad English.

Visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services

Comment: There are *lots* of examples floating around, showing how to make direct REST calls without the SDK. You can even look at the source code to the SDKs themselves.

Comment: I find a way to solve this.

You should use Shared Sing

Answer (score 0):

> I need a example to call the authentification service without sdk

We could  generate signature string and specify `Authorization` header for the request of performing Azure storage services without installing SDK. Here is a simple working sample to list the containers, you could refer to my `generateAuthorizationHeader` function and [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services) to construct the signature string.

```
string StorageAccount = "mystorageaccount";
string StorageKey = "my storage key";

string requestMethod = "GET";
string mxdate = "";
string storageServiceVersion = "2014-02-14";

protected void btnlist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list",
    StorageAccount
    ));

    req.Method = requestMethod;

    //specify request header
    string AuthorizationHeader = generateAuthorizationHeader();
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader);
    req.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", mxdate);
    req.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

    StringReader theReader = new StringReader(content);
    DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
    theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

    DataTable dt = theDataSet.Tables[2];

    }
}

public string generateAuthorizationHeader()
{
    mxdate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");

    string canonicalizedHeaders = string.Format(
        "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
        mxdate,
        storageServiceVersion);

    string canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/\ncomp:list", StorageAccount);

    string stringToSign = string.Format(
    "{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
    requestMethod,
    canonicalizedHeaders,
    canonicalizedResource);

    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey));

    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

    String authorization = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}",
    "SharedKey",
    StorageAccount,
    signature
    );

    return authorization;
}
```

Besides, please refer to [Azure Storage Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference) to know more about programmatic access to Azure Storage Services via REST APIs.

Comment: do you encounter problems while constructing the signature string?

Comment: Yes, I encounter a problem. 

The service response is "403 error" :(

Comment: I find a way to solve this.

You should use Shared Sing, here explain me:

1. Enter to Portal Azure
2. Open the Account Storage
3. In the General Information click on "Share sing access"
4. Enable all permissions that you need (In my case only a Enable File)

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve this.

You should use Shared Sing, here explain me:

1. Enter to Portal Azure
2. Open the Account Storage
3. In the General Information click on "Share sing access"
4. Enable all permissions that you need (In my case only  Enable "File")
5. Enable all resources permission that you need (In my case onl Enable "Service, Container and Object")
6. Define and Start Date and End Date (This is the space of time that Shared Key will be valid)
7. Define protocol type (In my case use HTTPS)
8. Clic on "Generate SAS" button

After this process you will get a token like this:
?sv=2016-05-31&ss=f&srt=sco&sp=rwdlc&se=2017-11-28T04:29:49Z&st=2017-02-18T20:29:49Z&spr=https&sig=rt7Loxo1MHGJqp0F6ryLhYAmOdRreyiYT418ybDN2OI%3D

10. You have to use this Token like Autentication

Example Call Code List a Content:

```
    public with sharing class CallAzureRestDemo {

public string token = '&sv=2016-05-31&ss=f&srt=sco&sp=rwdlc&se=2017-02-19T04:00:44Z&st=2017-02-18T20:00:44Z&spr=https&sig=GTWGQc5GOAvQ0BIMxMbwUpgag5AmUVjrfZc56nHkhjI%3D';
//public Integer batchSize;


public CallAzureRestDemo(){}    


public void getlistcontent(String endpoint)
{        
    // Create HTTP GET request
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint+token);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res;

    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '@@RESPONSE: '+res);

    // only do this if not running in a test method
    if(!Test.isRunningTest())
    {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Sending the message to Azure');
        res = http.send(req);                
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'http.send result status: ' + res.getStatus());
    }
    else
    {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Running in a test so not sending the message to Azure');
    }
}
```

}

Example TestMethod:

```
@isTest
```

private class Test_CallAzureRestDemo {

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

    CallAzureRestDemo oRest = new CallAzureRestDemo();          

    try{
        //Call the method and set endpoint
        oRest.getlistcontent('https://accountstoragecomex.file.core.windows.net/?comp=list');
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('@@'+e);
    }
  }
```

}

Example to Response:

20:15:47.64 (79388244)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[100]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=h*t*t*p*s://accountstoragecomex.file.core.windows.net/?comp=list&sv=2016-05-31&ss=f&srt=sco&sp=rwdlc&se=2017-02-19T04:00:44Z&st=2017-02-18T20:00:44Z&spr=h*t*t*p*s&sig=GTWGQc5GOAvQ0BIMxMbwUpgag5AmUVjrfZc56nHkhjI%3D, Method=GET]
20:15:47.64 (395755012)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[100]|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]

Example Call Service "FILE - Get List Share"

[Call To List Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM9pD.png)

One more time, Sorry for my bad english.